# String of doublequotes and commas added to my table made with bootstrap - what is happening here?

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am quite new to programming.

I have a webpage that displays a table using the bootstrap framework. I am using wordpress as my CMS.

When the page loads a string of doublequoutes and commas ““, ““, ““, appears above the table. These are not in my html code as I have written it, they appear on page load.

```
<div class="container">
<p>Some words</p>
<table class="table table-hover">
<tbody>
<tr><td>content etc etc</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

[This is the page](http://www.xterrace.com/hat16-featured-milliners/) to which I am referring.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check PHP side if you output something before table

Comment: Those characters do exist in the html code of your page just after the paragraph. Maybe they are generated by something, so check that.

Comment: Indeed, but where have they come from?

Comment: check you change function that is what causing it.

at line 27 there is an exception : elem.innerHTML = text[counter];

Exception
:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at change (http://www.xterrace.com/wp-content/themes/the-x-terrace-theme/js/main.js?ver=4.5.3:27:21)
message:"Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"


this error may be because the script is loaded before the element was loaded on the page.

again i am not sure if  this is causing doubleqoutes and commas but this is one of the error on the web page. try removing it and it may solve your issue.

Comment: @SanketPatel I don't think that is it. Put a breakpoint in the `change()` function and you can see that the `"", "", "",` is on the page before the first time that function gets called. It only gives the error because there is no element with the ID `changeText`.

Comment: I think your best bet is to check like Justinas and Jylo have suggested. Look at your page markup to see if anything could be creating that `"", "", "",` string immediately before the table with the "London Hat Week..." header. I'm guessing you can't attach a debugger to a wordpress site, so this may be a little difficult...